# What data (if any) persists across web-requests in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, singleton, persistence, controller

I decided to use the **singleton** design pattern while creating a view helper class.  This got me thinking; will the singleton *instance* survive across requests?  This led to another question, **Which variables (if any) survive across web requests** and does that change depending on deployment? (Fastcgi, Mongrel, Passenger, ...)

I know that Controller instance variables aren't persisted. I know Constants are persisted (or reloaded?). But I don't know about class variables, instance variables on a class, Eigenclasses, ...

Comment: Your helpers are loaded automatically by the framework, you shouldn't have to second guess by building your own loading mechanism.

Comment: I was creating a Singleton because I needed to encapsulate some re-usable bit of functionality and some state information.  I was just wondering about the state information and if it would persist across requests if done in the typical fashion (using a class variable of the singleton).  The solution was for me was to store the singleton instance in a controller instance variable and have a single traditional helper method return that instance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The simple answer is none. Each request is treated as an independent event and no state information is carried over apart from what is stored in the user session and any external databases, caches, or file stores. It is best that you design your application with this in mind and not expect things to persist just because you've set them.

The more complicated story is that some things do persist. For example, you can create a class variable on a controller and this will be carried from one request to the next as you might expect. The catch is that this only applies to the singular instance of that controller, as contained within that process, and will not apply to requests served by other processes. If you need caching, make use of the Rails.cache infrastructure and avoid hacking in your own.

A typical production environment is a complicated, ever-changing thing, where processes are created and destroyed constantly and there is no way to determine in advance which process will ultimately end up serving a particular request. As many deployments involve not only multiple processes on a single machine, but multiple machines, there really is no practical way to create application-wide singleton objects.

The best thing you can do is build a layer on top of the caching engine where your singleton object is merely a wrapper to functions that fetch and write from the cache. This gives you the appearance of a singleton object while maintaining inter-process consistency.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I actually want to avoid having my singleton shared across requests. This concern prompted the above question. I think I'll end up using a helper method that instantiates or returns a single instance stored in a controller instance variable. (i.e. `def name_of_view_helper_class; @singleton ||= ViewHelperClass.new; end`)  Does this make sense?

Comment: Creating controller instance variables, or even variables within helpers that are re-used throughout the execution of the request, is a fairly standard thing to be doing. The instance of the controller and all the associated variables are destroyed at the end of the request, so you always start with a clean slate each time.

Comment: There's also a second catch: production and non-production environment behaves differently. What this response says is true, but only for a production environment: instances variables are not carried from request to request in other environment, unless specified otherwise in the configuration.

Comment: @user626921 In the development environment even less persists between requests since classes are reloaded, discarding any modifications that might've been made. Cache variables on helpers and controller classes will be reset.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this post is old, but for who is looking a solution, it's possible to use Rails.Cache, like this:

```
class TestEventsController < ApplicationController
  require 'httparty'

  @@cache = ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore.new(expires_in: 5.minutes)

  before_action :get_data, only: [:get]
  before_action :get_response, only: [:set]

  def get
    uri = "https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/zap_id/"
    event_id = event_id_generate()
    @@cache.write(event_id, "")

    result = HTTParty.post(uri.to_str,
    :body => {id: event_id, data: @data}.to_json,
    :headers => {'content-Type' => 'application/json'})
    sleep 2
    render json: { 'value': @@cache.read(event_id) }, status: 200
  end

  def set
    @@cache.write(@id, @value)
    render json: { 'value': @@cache.read(@id) }, status: 200
  end

  def get_data
    @data = params["data"]
  end
  def get_response
    @id = params["id"]
    @value = params["value"]
  end

  def event_id_generate
    token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(10, false)
  end
end
```

What I'm doing is receive a request in a route, sending a GET to Zapier, and waiting for the answer in another route. Rails opens a new Thread for each request, so I write in the RAM my data in format 'key: value'

[Rails.cache in different threads not caching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33703928/rails-cache-in-different-threads-not-caching)

Answer (score -3):

The web is a stateless medium. Unless you purposely save data in a session or pass it in a get or post, each web request starts with a blank slate. Any objects created with the current request are destroyed once the page is delivered to the web browser.

Comment: You can inadvertently create persistent state information if you make the mistake of using class variables instead of class instance variables, though, stateless or not. The server has a lot of state information that needs to be compartmentalized in order to not inadvertently carry state from one request to the next, or one session to another.