# Cache instance variable after refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, instance-variables

I've 3 models: Game, Player, Card.

In Game model i've function:

```
def cards
    @cards ||= Card.all.shuffle
end
```

When i'm dealing cards to players i do:

```
player.cards << cards.pop
```

i'm trying to save cards variable, that after refresh i can deal to another player from the remain cards.

Basically i'm trying to avoid remain cards calculation in that way:

```
  def remain_cards
    all_cards = Card.all
    table_cards = players.map(&:cards).flatten

    all_cards - table_cards
  end
```

Is there any way to do that?

It's a BlackJack game, The Game Cycle:

- human player enter into the game and click on start game button and ajax request sent to server
- the Game model deals two cards to each player, first bots players and then human players.
- after the starting dealing, i'm sending back the all data which includes players and their cards.
- then i want thatת if player clicks on the 'hit me' button, that will add him random card from the remain cards

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a little more detail on what's going on?  What do you mean by refresh?

Update:  In that case I believe the simple answer is no.  "Each request is treated as an independent event and no state information is carried over apart from what is stored in the user session and any external databases, caches, or file stores. It is best that you design your application with this in mind and not expect things to persist just because you've set them." (source: [What data (if any) persists across web-requests in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791093/what-data-if-any-persists-across-web-requests-in-ruby-on-rails)).  The only other thing I can think of to allow the "cards" data to persist across requests is by using a cookie.  But then you'd have to keep updating the cookie info anyway I believe.  So it may be better or not depending on what your situation is.

Update: I've been thinking...One possible way to have a "card deck" persist is to try something like the following:

```
#config/initializers/card.rb - store an instance to an app-wide Card object using an initializer.
THE_CARD_DECK = Card.new

#Now we change the before filter which sets the @cards variable to use that constant:
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :init_cards
  def init_cards
    @cards = THE_CARD_DECK
  end
end
```

Now @cards should be the sole card deck and you can change its value throughout the game.